# Which collections are permissible for javax.persistence.ManyToMany

Tags: collections, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

Researching I found that `javax.persistence.ManyToMany` relationship can be implemented various collection. I wonder if all `java.util` collections are permissible or if there are restrictions.

Note that I actually use Scala and I love to use one of the immutable collections. But I guess that is out of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Hibernate Documentation it only says:

> You can map Collection, List, Map and
>   Set pointing to associated entities as
>   one-to-many or many-to-many
>   associations using the @OneToMany or
>   @ManyToMany annotation respectively.
>   If the collection is of a basic type
>   or of an embeddable type, use
>   @ElementCollection. We will describe
>   that in more detail in the following
>   subsections.

Source: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association-collections

Comment: Thanks. I did not look at the Hibernate Documentation because I thought Hibernate ≠ JPA.

Comment: JPA is the specification, Hibernate is a implementation of this specification. There are also other implementations.